# How to factor it?

Tags: factoring

I only know how to factor the usual one, something like x^2+x+1.

Now I have this:

y-xy

And just lost as to how to factor it.

How can I factor it?

Comment: factor out the $y$

Comment: How do you factor $x^2+x+1$?

Answer (score 1):

As simply as 
$$y(1-x)$$
$\phantom{asd}$